# MVC3 using nHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I have an MVC3 project using nHibernate, Rhino and Castle.  I finally got all of the components in place.  I think.  At least it runs and invokes the IWondsorContainer CreateContainer() method....after that method, the Application_Start does not fire and I get the message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Views/Proposal/Index.cshtml
```

Any ideas?  I don't know what to make of this.  Thanks

Comment: Try going to the url `/proposal/index`. The above error suggests that you are trying to go directly to the View without passing through routing and the controller.

Comment: @Charlino...I still get the same result when I use /proposal/index or /....ideas?

Comment: You get the same result, as in you get the same error page complaining about the resource not being found?

Comment: @Charlino...same result as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be requesting a view directly: `/Views/Proposal/Index.cshtml`. In ASP.NET MVC you do not request a view. You request a controller action. So in your browser the url should be `/Proposal/Index` or simply `/` depending on how your routes are configured.

I suspect that you had the focus on this `Index.cshtml` when you hit <kbd>F5</kbd> in Visual Studio which has this ugly habit of following the url. You could define a start url in the properties of your web project to avoid this behavior.

Comment: OK, cool....I tried to set the property in the project but it didn't like Proposal/Index as the specific URL.  What should it be?

Comment: @MikeTWebb, what it didn't like about `Proposal/Index`?

Comment: @Darin...same result.  404 page not found